# set image to imageview in uicollectionview that is in uitableviewcell xib

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have taken a `UITableView` and deque a `UITableViewCell` XIB and set data to a label in it, also I have `UICollectionView` in `UITableViewCell` XIB in which I have to set images in a `UICollectionViewCell`.

***UIImageView is in UICollectionViewCell and respective UICollectionView is in UITableViewCell so how to set an image to that UIImageView?***

also have tableview delegate function in one file

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.discoverData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "discoveryTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! discoveryTableViewCell
    let data = discoverData[indexPath.row]
    cell.messageLbl.text = (data["content"] as! String)

    // This how normally image is set in tableview, how to do with collectionview
    cell.userImage.pin_updateWithProgress = true
    let riderImage = URL(string: (data["profile_pic"] as! String))
    cell.userImage.pin_setImage(from: riderImage, placeholderImage: nil, completion: nil)
    return cell
}
```

**collection view delegate function in UITableViewCell.**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return numCell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "discoverCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! discoverCollectionViewCell
    cell.postImage.backgroundColor = .cyan
    return cell
}
```

Here is a picture of how it looks yellow box is UICollectionView and cyan color box is UIImageView.

[image]

Comment: so what is the question :D ?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: UIImageView is in UICollectionViewCell and respective UICollectionView is in UITableViewCell so how to set an image to that UIImageView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `cellForRowAt indexPath`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "discoveryTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! discoveryTableViewCell
    if let data = discoverData[indexPath.row] as? [String: Any] {
        cell.messageLbl.text = (data["content"] as! String)

        cell.data = data
    }
    return cell
}
```

In your "discoveryTableViewCell" (It should be "DiscoveryTableViewCell") :

```
var data: [String: Any] {
    didSet {
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "discoverCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! discoverCollectionViewCell

    if let profilePic = data["profile_pic"] as? String {
        let riderImage = URL(string: profilePic)
        cell.postImage.pin_setImage(from: riderImage, placeholderImage: nil, completion: nil)
    }

    return cell
}
```

You should follow the proper style guide and naming conventions in Swift. 
Please check this URL for better understanding:

- https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide